# Remove ".local" suffix on local server (Yosemite)

Tags: apache, server, virtualhost

I'm running a local server manually using apache virtual hosts. Everything works fine, but the "problem" (it's not a real problem, actually) is that I'm struggling to remove the ".local" suffix I declared on "hosts" file before. 
Even if I set `ServerName Application1` or `ServerAlias Application1` on apache config file, it doesn't work.

For the time being, it run as `application1.local/index.html` and I'd like to run just as `application1/index.html`.

Comment: Show your `/etc/hosts` file

Comment: now you asked, I realized it was missing a line `127.0.0.1 application1` instead only `127.0.0.1 application.local`!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself by setting the ServerName on Apache virtual-host config file as `application1` (without suffix) and changing /etc/hosts file to `127.0.0.1 application1` and `127.0.0.1 application1.local` and then restarting Apache.